# NFC spectrum analysis, weird frequencies showing

Tags: nfc, spectrum-analyzer

I apologize for the picture quality, I did not have an opportunity to export the screenshots.

I have a problem properly interpreting this signal. The subcarrier peak is visible but the data seems to be noisy? I assume using a pre amplifier wouldn't get me a better result. There are also two peaks visible on the leftmost and rightmost side of the screen and I have no idea where they come from. This is the response of an ISO14443-A Tag:

Are the settings of the analyzer wrong or is this the proper spectrum?

[image: subcarrier spectrum]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Firstly, info for non proffesionals:

`ISO14443-A`: https://www.msoos.org/largefiles/rfid_soos_pres.pdf

The subcarrier is at fc/16, so your subcarrier is at `13.56 * 15 / 16 = 12.7125`

Glossary: https://www.nfc-research.at/index.php@id=40.html

> PCD
>
> Proximity coupling device: a transmitter that can read tags based on ISO14443 (PICC). The reader emits an electromagnetic field that powers a tag/transmitter by inductivity. Communicates with PICC using load modulation scheme.
>
> PICC
>
> Proximity inductive coupling card: a transponder that can be read or written by a proximity reader. Theses tags are based on the ISO14443 standard. Such tags do not have a power supply like a battery, but are powered by the electromagnetic field of the reader (PCD)

### The info you provide

> This is the response of an ISO14443-A Tag

So, this is how the card communicates with the base. Using the pdf previously provided,

> PICC→PCD:
>
> Load modulation
>
> Subcarrier: fc/16 → fc/128
>
> Coding: OOK, Manchester
>
> Bandwidth: 106kbit/s→847kbit/s

The communication the card transfers to you is using OOK, on-off-key: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-off_keying.

One of the most visual caracteristic OOK using an oscilloscope is there is a lot of noise around the frequency of transmission. That's why you see lot's of, apparently, noise.

On-off-keying sends pulses (deformed pulses), so... where are the harmonics?

### The peaks

The peaks your oscilloscope snitches are, indeed, the harmonics of the on-off-keying.

Did you perceive that the frequency between the center of transmission, 13.56, and one of the peak, is exactly the frequency between the center of transmission and your subcarrier?

That's exactly what happens in your image.

Comment: Is the "noise" around the carrier the phase-noise of the PLL controlling the carrier?

Comment: The "noise" is the spectrum of the message sended. The PLL noise would be very near (around hertz), and the phase-noise would be valid if the message would be with phase shifting, but on-off is, literally, with the same phase, changing it's amplitude.

If you check the fourier transform of an OOK transmision around 12.7125 Mhz, you will see that "noise" perfectly.

Shares properties with FSK.

Answer (score 0):

These look like the first overtones of your peak at M1 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtone), judging by the relatively even spacing, and how both appear to be at -93dB.

For noise reduction, it depends very much on the rest of your system whether you go analog or digital, but I'm guessing that in your case with NFC, you should consider using a RLC bandpass filter, and then perhaps some kind of lower order FIR/IIR filter to take the edge off the noise, although I'm not too familiar with the specifics of that system.